The classification of finitely generated modules over the ring of (Laurent polynomials in multiple variables)
Let  $M=\mathbb Z [x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_n^{\pm1}]$ be the ring of Laurent polynomials in multiple variables. May I ask if there are known results that give the classification/nice description of the finitely generated modules over the $M$? In the case when $n=1$, i.e. when we have a single variable, a nice description can be found in a paper by Daniel S. Silver and Susan G. Williams, which contains the following theorem:

We denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[t, t^{-1}\right]$ of Laurent
polynomials by $\Lambda$. It is a Noetherian unique factorization
domain.
Proposition 2.4. Assume that $M$ is a finitely generated
$\Lambda$-module.
There exists a pair $U, B$ of finitely generated abelian groups and monomorphisms $f, g: U \rightarrow B$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to
the infinite free product $$\cdots \oplus_U B \oplus_U B \oplus_U
 \cdots$$
with identical amalgamations $B \stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} U
 \xrightarrow{f} B$;

May I ask if there is any known work that can generalise this result to the multivariable case? Any reference would be really appreciated.
(This question is copied from Math StackExchange)

There will be a finitely generated abelian group $B$, finitely generated abelian groups $U_1,\dots, U_n$, and monomorphisms $f_i,g_i \colon U_i \to B$  such that $M$ is isomorphic to the pushout of a higher-dimensional analogue of that diagram: Specifically, the pushout of a diagram with infinitely many copies of $B$, indexed by $\mathbb Z^n$, and infinitely many copies of each $U_i$, indexed by $\mathbb Z^n$, with arrows $f_i$ from each $U_i$ to the copy of $B$ with the same index and $g_i$ from each $U_i$ to the copy of $B$ with the $i$th standard unit vector added to the index.
This pushout can be expressed as the $M$-module given by $M \otimes_{\mathbb Z} B$ together with relations $f_i(a) - x_i g_i(a)$ for each element $a$ in some fixed generating set of each $U_i$. Thus, it suffices to check that each finitely generated $M$-module can be expressed as $M \otimes_{\mathbb Z} B$ modulo one or more relations of the form $z - x_i y$ with $z,y \in B$.
To do this, we take an arbitrary presentation and modify it until it has this form. The presentation will have some generators and some relations which are linear combinations of monomials times generators. We add new generators which are monomials times generators, so every relation is now a linear combination of generators or a relation which expresses one generator is a monomial times another generator. Now we can add new generators and relations until every relation is a linear combination of generators or a relation which expresses one generator as a variable times another generator. For example if we had $v = x_1^2 x_2^{-2} w$ we would add generators $v', v^*, w'$ and write $v = x_1 v'$, $v'= x_1 v^*$, $w'= x_2 v^*$, $w=x_2 w'$.
Now the generators and the relations which are linear combinations of generators give us an abelian group, and the other relations are of the form $z-x_i y$, as desired.

Thank you for your help Will. I have a quick question. In this case,  $x_i$'s are commuting automorphisms on $M$. Because of the commutativity of $x_i$'s, are there going to be some restrictions on $f_i$'s and $g_i$'s?

@ghc1997 No. The commutativity is enforced by the $\mathbb Z^n$ indexing. No further enforcement of commutativity is needed. (The $f_i$s and $g_i$s represent relations. No restrictions are placed on the relations of an $R$-module by identities like commutativity satisfied by $R$. Those identities are only needed to construct the free $R$-module which we later quotient by the relations.)

Thank you for explaining that.
Sorry, I am new to module theory. I have a question about the term "pushout". Suppose we have chosen our $f_1$, $g_1$, and $U_1$. Are there any restrictions on what $f_2$, $g_2$, and $U_2$ can be due to the choice of $f_1$, $g_1$, and $U_1$?
I am referring to this diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)#Universal_property)

@ghc1997. No, since the requirement that the diagram commutes is vacuous in this case as there are no two parts with the same start and end.

Sorry to bother you again. In the case when $n=2$, this is how I visualise the module
$$ \begin{matrix}
& \vdots &   & \vdots &   \
\ldots & B & \bigoplus_{U_1} & B & \ldots \
& \bigoplus_{U_2} &   & \bigoplus_{U_2} &  \
\ldots & B & \bigoplus_{U_1} & B & \ldots \
& \vdots &   & \vdots &
\end{matrix}  $$
Then $x_1$ shifts coordinate one place to the right, and $x_2$ shifts coordinate one place up.
Introducing $f_i$, $g_i$ and $U_i$ is like quotient out by some relations.
Is this the correct way of thinking about it?

I was trying to look at some examples. After I defined $f_1$, $g_1$ and $U_1$, it seems to me that $f_2$ and $g_2$ have to commute with $f_1$ and $g_1$ in some sense?

@ghc1997 Your picture looks good to me, but as to the commutation, I don't see why this should be the case. Can you give an example where they don't commute and this causes a problem?

Thank you so much for your time.
For simplicity, let $U_1 = U_2 = B = \mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $f_i$s be the identity maps.
Now let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be the maps corresponding to two non-commuting matrices, let's call them $M_1$,  $M_2 \in \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb Z)$.
We have $x_1$ shifts coordinate one place to the right, but because of the relation, we can also view the action of $x_1$ as multiplying a vector in $B$ by $M_1$.
Similarly, $x_2$ shifts coordinate one place up, but we can also view the action of $x_2$ as multiplying a vector by $M_2$.

Now fix an ``origin" $B = B_{(0,0)}$. For all $v$ in $B$, we should have $x_1(x_2(v)) =  x_2(x_1(v)) $. However $M_1 M_2 \neq M_2 M_1$, it seems there is a contradiction here?

@ghc1997 No, this just forces elements some elements of $B$ to map to $0$ in $M$. Nothing in the statement says $B \to M$ is injective.
